# How to limit a Hadoop MapReduce job to a certain number of nodes?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

So, basically I have a system with 4 data nodes. However, to check the scalability of my hadoop application, I want to test it with 1, 2 and 4 nodes. So, how can I limit the number of nodes used by hadoop to only 1 or 2. I am using hadoop 2.5.1 and I don't have admin rights to the system. Moreover, how can I also control the number of cores used by hadoop for a node?

Comment: Did you check the hadoop documentation? I am sure its self sufficient.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I'm pretty sure such a thing does not exist. You only have two choices, writing a scheduler that limits placement to n-nodes or shutdown the remaining nodes and run your experiments.

Answer (score 2):

You need admin rights to do all that

**how can I limit the number of nodes used by hadoop to only 1 or 2.**

[Decommission](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.2/bk_hdp1-system-admin-guide/content/admin_decommission-slave-nodes-2-1.html) 2-3 nodes

**how can I also control the number of cores used by hadoop for a node**

set below config in yarn-site.xml to allocate 8 vcores per node

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>8</value>
</property>
```

also update yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator in capacity-scheduler.xml
because DefaultResourceCalculator only uses memory.

```
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator</value>
    <description>
      The ResourceCalculator implementation to be used to compare
      Resources in the scheduler.
      The default i.e. DefaultResourceCalculator only uses Memory while
      DominantResourceCalculator uses dominant-resource to compare
      multi-dimensional resources such as Memory, CPU etc.
    </description>   </property>
```